# One form, but different state

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm moving now from other technologies to React Native and I have a problem. I have one presentational component which is `<TaskInput />`.

```
const TaskInput = (props: ITaskInputProps) => {
      return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text> 
                  <TextInput
                     style={styles.input}
                     multiline
                     scrollEnabled={false}
                  />
            </View>
      )
}
```

ParentComponent over TaskInput

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import TaskInputContainer from '../task-input';

interface ITaskConfigurationProps {
      title: string,

      isInputForm?: boolean,
      isRequired?: boolean,
}

const TaskConfiguration = (props: ITaskConfigurationProps) => {
      return (
            <View style={(props.isRequired) ? [styles.container, {backgroundColor: '#f25e5e'}] : styles.container}>

                  { props.isInputForm && <TaskInputContainer title={props.title} /> }


            </View>
      );
}

export default TaskConfiguration;
```

```
const TaskScreen = (props: ITaskScreenProps) => {
      return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                  <SectionTitle title={'Task Settings'} />
                  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.configurations}>
                        <TaskConfiguration title={"What you need to do?"} isInputForm={true} isRequired={true} />
                        <TaskConfiguration title={"Description"} isInputForm={true} />
                        <TaskConfiguration title={"Deadline"} />
                        <TaskConfiguration title={"Priority"} />
                  </ScrollView>
                  <Button isDone={true} navigation={props.navigation} />
            </View>
      )
}
```

`TaskInput` component takes one prop which is `title` and it will be in two places on my screen. One component will be called "Enter main task", another one is "Description". But this component will accept different states like `currentMainTextInput` and `currentDescriptionTextInput`. This is my idea of re-usable component TextInput, but I can't do what I want because if I set type in one input - other input will re-render with first input (both of them are one presentational component).

I want to use this dumb component in any place of my app. I don't want to create a new identical component and duplicate code, How can I do that? (P.S. I was thinking about "redux or class/hooks", but what should I use...)

Comment: Hello @Redial, Yes, you can do this. Can you show me whole TaskInput component code? You can do it with `React Hooks` as `FunctionalComponent`. I just need to see the whole component to provide you with the solution :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your improving of my text :) That's whole component code, nothing more but "export default .... "

Comment: Hi, please show the parent component

Comment: @IanVasco, that's it

Comment: Ok, just one more thing. What is "But this component will accept different states like currentMainTextInput and currentDescriptionTextInput". I don't get it TBH

Comment: @IanVasco, forgive me for my English :) In my redux-state will be two property - currentMainTextInputValue and currentDescriptionTextInputValue, for example. One of them for inputMainTask, and other - for inputDescriptionForTheTask